# Is it possible to create a SQL data base using a core data schema

Tags: mysql, sql, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a `core data` schema file with relationships between the entities.

I need to create a `SQL` database and would like to know if it can be created automatically (`MySql` or `MS-SQL`) using only this file.

Looking at the `SQLite` DB I see that the relationships are not mapped in any logical way.

Answer (score 1):

First, your assessment that the relationships are "not mapped in any logical way" is not correct. If you look carefully at the Core Data generated database you will discover that the relationships are mapped *exactly* as in any other old relational database scheme, i.e. with foreign keys referring to  rows in other tables.

Also, the naming conventions in these SQLite databases are very transparent (e.g., entity and attribute names start with `Z`, etc.

That being said, I would strongly discourage you to hack the Core Data generated database file, or even to use it to inform another database scheme, the reason being that these are undocumented features that could change any time without notice and thus break any code you write based on them.

IMO, the most practical thing to do is to rewrite the model quickly in the usual MySQL schema format and update it manually as well when you change the managed object model.

If you would like to automate the process, there is a rich set of APIs provided for interpreting and parsing `NSManagedObjectModel`, including classes like `NSEntityDescription`, `NSAttributeDescription` etc. You could write a framework that iterates though your entities and attributes and generates a text file that is a readable schema for MySQL, complete with information about indexing, versions etc..

If you go down that route, please make sure to notify us and do post your framework on Github for the benefit of others.

Comment: I have a fairly large core data scheme and wouldn't want to design the whole thing again.

Comment: I suggested an alternative solution. Plus, you do not have to re-design, just translate what is in the model into sql language.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Core Data you can create an SQL based database using a schema file but its structure is entirely controlled by the Core Data framework. Apple specifically tell us as developers to leave it alone and do not edit it using `libsqlite` or any other method. If you do then Core Data won't have anything to do with you!

In terms of making your own DB using one of Apple's schema files, I'm sure it is possible, but you'd have to know the inner workings of the Core Data framework to even attempt it.

In terms of making your own SQLite DB then you have to sort out all the relationships and mapping yourself.

I think that mixing and matching Core Data resources and custom built SQLite databases is probably a headache waiting to happen. I have used both methods and find that Core Data is brilliant (especially with iCloud) as long as you're OK with your App being limited to Apple only.